# Python If With no commands followed by a Else Syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, indentation

I'm writing a basic webscraping code, which basically will get the date and title of a post and, if the date >= a date stored in a SQL db and the title != from a title also stored in the DB, then do some stuff.

I'm getting a syntax error when executing it. Here's the code:

```
for i in web_results:
    py_newsdate = datetime.strptime(i.find('div', attrs={'class': "infoItem"}).find_all('p')[0].getText()[6:], '%d/%m/%Y')
    py_newstitle = i.find('h3').find('a')['title'] 

    if (py_newsdate < sql_latest[0][0] or py_newstitle == sql_latest[0][1]):
    else:
        py_newslink = i.find('h3').find('a')['href'] 
        web_results_final.append([py_newsdate, py_newstitle, py_newslink])

print(web_results_final)
```

And here's the error:

```
  File "searcher", line 37
    else:
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I know the blocks have to be properly idented, but I'm thinking the problem may be on this "empty" if.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no code in your `if` block. Add at least a comment line or `pass`!

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements

Answer (score 2):

Blocks need to be followed by something. If you have a block you intend to leave empty, then use the `pass` statement:

```
if (py_newsdate < sql_latest[0][0] or py_newstitle == sql_latest[0][1]):
    pass
else:
    py_newslink = i.find('h3').find('a')['href'] 
    web_results_final.append([py_newsdate, py_newstitle, py_newslink])
```

This is true whether you are trying to write the block inline or on multiple lines:

```
if 0: pass
else: print(2)
```

Note: you have to have a new line for an `else` block. This will not work:

```
if 0: pass; else: print(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be more efficient if you use,

```
if not (py_newsdate < sql_latest[0][0] or py_newstitle == sql_latest[0][1]):
    py_newslink = i.find('h3').find('a')['href'] 
    web_results_final.append([py_newsdate, py_newstitle, py_newslink])
```